Conditions for using the free() in function c
int *p;
p  = (int *) calloc(sizeof(int), 1000);
free(p);
free(&p[0]);

What is the different of free(p) and free(&p[0]), they can free memory or not?
And if I use free(&p[0]), can there be errors with different compilier?

You assigned the result from calloc to p, and therefore you should use free(p). The fact that &p[0] is in fact the same address (and therefore can work) doesn't change that.

If p is a valid pointer, then p and &p[0] are exactly equivalent for every purpose.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: No, they are not exactly equivalent. One is an lvalue, and the other is not. p can be assigned, and its address can be taken, but &p[0] cannot be assigned or have its address taken.

@EricPostpischil well p stands for arbitrary C expression, not necessarily an identifier. But you are right, when p is an lvalue &p[0] is not.

The way array notation works, a[b] is exactly the same as *(a+b).
This means that &p[0] is the same as &*(p + 0).
Also, if the & operator is immediately followed by either the * operator or the result of the [] operator, the & and * operators effectively cancel each other out.
This means that &p[0] and &*(p + 0) are the same as p + 0, which is simply p.
And because of the above, these two lines are equivalent:
free(p);
free(&p[0]);

This also means you can't do both as you've shown in your code, otherwise you're freeing a pointer value that has already been freed.


What is the different of free(p) and free(&p[0]), they can free memory or not?

No difference. They will both free the dynamic allocated memory.

if I use free(&p[0]), can there be errors with different compilier?

No. It's standard compliant.

p[0] is equivalent1 to *(p + 0), therefore the expression &p[0] is equivalent to &(*(p + 0)), which is equivalent2 to p + 0, which is the same as p.
So, &p[0] and p are equivalent, and you can use either as argument to free(), given that you obtained the pointer by an allocating function like calloc().
The expression &p[0] looks overly complex to mean p, and therefore you should avoid it. However, depending on (often deprecated) usage of macros, it could show up.

1 See for example chapter 6.5.2.1 of the C17 standard, which I happen to have opened. Because of the commutative nature of the operator +, you can conclude that *(0 + p) yields the same result, and so 0[p] is a sometimes seen in obfuscated source code.
2 See for example chapter 6.5.3.2 of the C17 standard, which I happen to have opened.
Do not attempt to free more than once.

Given:
int *p;
p  = (int *) calloc(sizeof(int), 1000);


if I use free(&p[0]), can there be errors with different compiler?

Yes - even with this compiler.

If p == NULL, &p[0] is undefined behavior.

calloc() returns a void *.  It may return a null pointer.

p is a pointer to an int.

If p != NULL, &p[0] is also a pointer to the same int.

If p != NULL, p == &p[0].

If p != NULL, p and &p[0] may/may not have the same bit patterns yet they have equivalent values and point to the same address.

free(p) is fine even if p == NULL.

free(&p[0]) is fine only if p != NULL.

free(p) coverts p to a void * and passes that pointer to free().

If p != NULL, free(&p[0]) coverts &p[0] to a void * and passes that pointer to free().


Summation: If p != NULL, free(&p[0]) and free(p) are equivalent.
Use free(p);
